# Convergence in $C([0, 1])$

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let's consider the space of continuous functions on the interval $[0, 1]$. We'll denote it by $C([0, 1])$.
Now we can define a sequence:
$$f_n(x) = x(1-x^n).$$
It's easy to find it's pointwise limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = g(x) = \begin{cases} x,\text{if } x\in[0, 1)\\0, \text{if } x = 1\end{cases}$$
I would like to show that the sequence does not converge in norm.
$$\left\lVert f_n- g \right\rVert = \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)-g(x)|$$
I don't know where to go from here. I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Comment: The sequence doesn't converge since $\|f_n - g\| = 1 \not\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for $x=1,$ $|f_n(x) - g(x)| = 0$. Hence
$$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-g(x) | = \sup_{x\in[0,1)}|f_n(x)-g(x)| = \sup_{x\in[0,1)} |x(1-x^n)-x| = \sup_{x\in[0,1)} |x^n| = 1, $$
for all $n$, so $f_n \not\to g$ uniformly.

Comment: It's quite strange for me that $\sup_{x \in [0, 1)} |x^n| = 1$. In Weierstrass theorem we need to have a closed subset $[a, b]$.

Comment: @Hendrra Notice that the limit function $g$ is not continuous, so that you can no longer guarantee that it attains its extrema (indeed, it does not, which is why I wrote $\sup$ instead of $\max$).

Comment: Thanks! One more question - $\sup_{x \in [0, 1)} |x^n| = 1$. That means that for a tiny $\epsilon$ we would have $(1 - \epsilon)^n = 1$. That's very strange for me. What is the reason why $\sup_{x \in [0, 1)} |x^n| = 1$?

Comment: @Hendrra This means that $1$ is the least upper bound of $|x^n|$ on $[0,1)$. In other words, you can get arbitrarily close to $1$ from below, i.e. for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $x \in [0,1)$ such that $1 - \epsilon < |x^n| \leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I was confused because I forgot that $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x^n$ is continuous, only $g$ the limit function is not continuos. Am I right?

Comment: @Hendrra Yes, $x^n$ is indeed continuous for all $n$, whereas $g$ is not.

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand it now although as I said before it's pretty confusing

Comment: @Hendrra Sketching the graph of your functions usually helps to visualize the situation. There is nothing strange going on here.